# is there a way to download a provisioning profile (with Jenkins or script) to build machine before a build?

Tags: ios, xcode, jenkins, profile, provisioning

I'm helping out someone building out a CI build for iOS on Jenkins and a situation came up where the provisioning profile that we were using was expired on the build machine, but was current in the dev portal.  So, the question came up if there was a way to download it before any build to make sure that the provisioning profile was up to date.

I've looked and haven't found anything solid and was wondering if anyone has done something like this (and if so, any pointers would be appreciated).

Thanks!
Mike

Comment: In addition to What Gary Riches notes below, I found out that HockeyApp also has some APIs that can do this as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sigh can be integrated with Jenkins and will manage all the provisioning: https://github.com/fastlane/sigh

Comment: Awesome.  I didn't know about this.  It looks to have some other interesting things it can do as well!  Thanks!